# Wiring up a ceiling fan using 3 way and 4 way switches

Tags: electrical, switch

I’m installing a ceiling fan with a remote and I have 3 way switches and 4 way switches to that fan. I want to use the remote and the wall switches. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You generally can't use switches *and* remote. Model of fan/remote? The likely solution will be smart switches with one of them as a remote. What actual functionality do you need? Actual remote or multiple fixed locations? Dim? Speed?

Comment: I know that I can use a relay in the fan box to use the remote and switch. I wanted to know if I can use multiple wall switches in different locations. You said I can use a smart switch- do the make it for ceiling fans with light and speed control?

Comment: Yes there are smart switches designed for fan and light control

Comment: Ok do you the name of the smart switches / so I can get them

Comment: Are you OK with ditching the remote that came with the fan and using some other product instead? Also, do you have room for two separate single gang switches at at least one of the switch locations?